# What are these river/canyon-like carvings in the ocean?

Tags: oceanography, rivers, satellite-oddities

Browsing around Google Maps, I came across this off the south-west coast of Ireland

[image: Continental shelf southwest of Ireland]

It looks very consistent with the shape rivers and their tributaries might make, but it has me puzzled since it's all underwater!

The main, most "river-like" one is in the middle-left of the picture but there are more (which look more like fjords) at the bottom.

What caused this feature?

Comment: So you discovered the Gollum channel system, nice (it really is called so). Have an extensive read at wikipedia on [submarine canyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_canyon), then return with further questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The carvings are submarine canyons, a part of the continental slope leading from the continental shelf to the continental rise and ultimately the Abyssal plains. They are a product of :

- erosion through currents and
- slumping of the continental shelf

Like other erosive or slumping effects, they can be self-reinforcing, leading to canyon-like structures. The highlighted canyon here is the Gollum Channel system, seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_canyon#/media/File:Porcupine_Biscay_canyons.png).